# Android - get image inside imageview to fill completely

Tags: java, android, imageview

I have a bitmap which I am reading from a particular location on the device like such and am setting the image to an ImageView

```
    scaledBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
    ivImage.setImageBitmap(scaledBitmap);
```

And thats how I am setting the xml code for that imageview

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

Is there a way I can remove the blank space above the image inside the ImageView?

[image]

Comment: first, make sure that the blank space above the image isn't part of the image.

Comment: please post your complete code... i think your blank space is a part of image

Answer (score 2):

Try Change `android:scaleType="fitXY"` to `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`

Comment: Is there any difference when apply this? Can you post the image file?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and what I remember is removing adjustViewBounds attribute line from code will fix it. Try this and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

`scaleType="fitCenter"` (default when omitted)

- will make it as wide as the parent allows and up/down-scale as needed keeping aspect ratio.

`scaleType="centerInside"`

- if the intrinsic width of `src` is smaller than parent width
  will center the image horizontally
- if the intrinsic width of `src` is larger than parent width
  will make it as wide as the parent allows and down-scale keeping aspect ratio.

It doesn't matter if you use `android:src` or `ImageView.setImage*` methods and the key is probably the `adjustViewBounds`.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```